# #20 in com.example.hellocompat:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class TextView .....in android

Tags: java, android, xml, exception

*Installation successful but App launch fails and logcat show this error "#20 in com.example.hellocompat:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class TextView"*

One thing I noticed, is that if I used this same layout to some other project then it ran very smoothly without having any frustrating issue and that projects also having the same code as in themes.xml file.

> Code inside MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void changeColor(View view) {      // onClick method 

    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="@string/textView_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="changeColor"
        android:text="@string/change_color"
        android:textSize="@string/button_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.HelloCompat" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: `android:textSize="@string/textView_text_size"`  , textsize is a string value, It should be a int value or passed using dimen

Comment: In the future, please post the entire stack trace.  Particularly for "Error inflating" because the real error is always the second exception in the stack.

Comment: Thank you Nitish, It really worked . Now I am thinking...  how good developer I am, ha ha....

Comment: Yah ! @GabeSechan after your comment I checked it up , and it really to the point. Thank you, it will help me in future errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nitish told , we need to use dimen to pass int value to textSize. And it just solved the problem.
And @GabeSechan's point is also right as stack trace having real error below this exception. Have a look.

[image: Stack trace]